# how to implementing a drag/scale/resize/rotate label within my view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, resize, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I want to create label which can be drag/drop/resize/rotate  with one finger touch. And also want to create frame like shown in image. if i touch and drag **square** it will scale label's height and width & by touching **round** will rotate the label. Please help me

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You already know about `UIGestureRecognizer` since you added that tag. What's the *specific* problem you're facing? Don't expect people to write your code for you.

Comment: Plz givz me daz coooode!!! Please read up on how to ask questions on  SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very easy to use open source project by Stephen Poletto that can be used to resize views:

[SPUserResizableView](https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView)

[image]

Place a label as a subview to the resizable view and you will achieve what you are after. The SPUserResizeableView can be implemented as e.g.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 150);
SPUserResizableView *userResizableView = [[SPUserResizableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
userResizableView.contentView = contentView;
[self.view addSubview:userResizableView];
```

Don't forget to to release if you are not using ARC. Hope it helps!

Comment: No problem; Wouldn't mind a +1 and an accepted answer though.^^ And please, really read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) so you can formulate a better question next time. :)

Comment: Thanks Flip for helping me. This SPUserResizableView is amazing . You saved my time :) .

Comment: I have add some code to rotate this SPUserResizableView.View is rotating successfully but after that i am not able to resize it :( its bcoz of i'm using CGAffineTransformRotate and i'm stuck to get it working properly

Comment: Was wondering why this is the answer if supplied lib does not support rotate?

Comment: @BradMoore The answer was shortly formulated since the question in truth doesn't belong here. Questions that is similar (in any way) to "Please give me code..." belong on an outsourcing website not on SO!

Comment: @Filip, the OP said "Please help me" not "Please give me the code". Thought giving help was what SO was all about? OP even got the item to rotate using this code with his existing code as he mentioned in his above post.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you this [GestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html):

I hope it helps you to better understand to all gestures. Thanks